# Stata: save residuals from regressions by group in a single variable

Tags: loops, stata

In Stata I want to run multiple regressions by group and save the corresponding residuals in a single variable. This is a working example of what I'm trying to do:

```
sysuse auto, clear

forvalues i=0/1 {
regress price mpg if foreign==`i'
predict r_`i' if foreign==`i', resid
}

egen residuals=rowtotal(r_0-r_1) , missing
drop r_0-r_1
```

While the above loop works just fine, my guess is that there must exist a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: "must" is a strong word here. You could certainly program that but I don't think there is an existing dedicated command. From Stata's point  of view you are combining results from several regressions. It offers `statsby` as a more general tool for that, but `statsby` is focused on scalars, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `statsby`:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/auto2 
statsby _b, by(foreign) verbose nodots: regress price weight length mpg
```

Comment: Unfortunately `statsby` will not help with saving residuals, as already pointed out.

Comment: Not so; only the residuals from the **last** regression run are accessible once `statsby` is done.

Comment: I mean you can compute them using your parameters estimates

Comment: The calculation by hand method is certainly possible although often awkward and error-prone if you have many predictors. I think you should spell out the code on how to do it in an expanded answer, as it's the nub of the question.

Comment: The strategy implied requires a `merge` of `statsby` results with the original dataset before hand calculation of residuals.

Comment: Yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `tempname` to create the local variables inside the loop. Then, we update our `res` (residuals) variable. After the loop finished, the `tempname` will be deleted automatically. Here is my code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
* @Pilik's code:

forvalues i=0/1 {
    regress price mpg if foreign==`i'
    predict r_`i' if foreign==`i', resid
}
egen res = rowtotal(r_0-r_1) , missing
drop r_0-r_1

* My code: use `tempname`
gen res1 = .
forvalues i=0/1 {
    regress price mpg if foreign==`i'
    tempname r
    predict `r' if foreign==`i', resid
    replace res1 = `r' if foreign==`i'
}
* Compare two ways: same results
su res res1
```

Comment: You will therefore create as many temporary variables as there are groups. They will disappear at the end of your program or session, but they will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

`rangestat` from SSC allows this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
rangestat (reg) price mpg, int(foreign 0 0) 
gen residual = price - b_cons - b_mpg * mpg
```

The method extends to moving windows as well as disjoint groups.